# swift iOS what ways can I cache network calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

The first thing a user has to do when he/she is launching my app is to select a category and a sub-category from two table views. (relational)

I populate the table views by calling my remote API/Server and the output the data.

But is there a way to cache the data so that I don't have to make a API network call every time?

Comment: What about writing the last response to a file and checking that first?

Comment: How do you want to cache and how do you decide not to use the cached data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the data returned from the API calls and manually save them on the disk [Explanation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html)

Also you can use core data this is a bit more troubling in the beginning but after the initial setup it is pretty easy to use.

Comment: Thanks will look into serialize. Core data seems so messy to get started with